# Recover xcode project from installed app on iPhone

Tags: xcode

I exedentaly deleted my xCode project, but I still have app installed on my iPhone. Is it somehow possible to retrieve at least some part of original project files from app itself?

Comment: You can't. It's compiled, and should take more time to reverse engineer the .app. You should be able to retrieve easily the assets tough. Don't you use Git, SVN, TimeMachine or another kind of stuff like that?

Comment: How could I retrieve assets? Unfortunately I did not use Git, SNV, TimeMachine or anything like that. I did however had a copy on USB flash drive, but it was deleted as well...

Comment: Using an explorer, you may be able to get the .app/.ipa back, right click on it once on your Mac, `Show Package Contents`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to do this.

You may be able to recover the original archive file created prior to installation on your device from inside the following directory (depending on how you deleted the original project) which may be of help.

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/

Comment: I simply deleted project folder. Archives folder is emty, but DerivedData contains a lot of files including my app files, although format is not the usual xCode format. Is DerivedData any good?

Comment: DerivedData is produced during the build process, it definitely won't help you recover the source but it may possibly have some assets you could recover.